# Markov Chains (probability of event not occurring)

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a transition matrix $$P(3X3) = \begin{pmatrix} 0.3& 0.7& 0\\
                                     0.4 &0 &  0.6\\
                                     0   &0.5& 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$$

Starting with level $0$ on the top left and moving down to level $2$ towards the bottom.

Question: If the person starts on level $0$ what is the probability they will not reach level $2$ once in the next four years?

I have tried multiple things such as calculating the probability of reaching level 2 at each year then multiplying those together and subtracting them from one but I don't get the right answer for any. Please help.

Comment: What is the right answer?

Comment: I don't have what the answer is

Comment: make level 2 an absorbing state....

Comment: By “not reach level 2 once in the next four years” do you mean that the process doesn’t enter state 2 at any time during that period?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: What is meant by $P(3X3)$? This notation is foreign to me.

Comment: It is just saying the transition matrix is P and its a 3x3 matrix

Comment: From a comment on a deleted answer: "The question states that there is a short way to solve this problem and a long way. I am wondering what the short way is."

Comment: @KombatWombat this is essential information that you should add in along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the question I assume you are trying to ask:

> A person starts on level zero among levels $0,1,2$, and can transition between levels every year.  The probabilities of each transition are given in the transition matrix $$P_{3 \times 3} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.3& 0.7& 0\\
>                                      0.4 &0 &  0.6\\
>                                      0   &0.5& 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Where $P_{ij}$ denotes the probability of moving from level $i-1$ to level $j-1$.
>
> Question: If the person starts on level $0$ what is the probability they will not reach level $2$ once in the next four years?

Following an idea from the comments: if we make level 2 an absorbing state, i.e. if we replace the bottom row with $(0,0,1)$ to form the matrix $Q$, then the probability of reaching level 2 at some point is the $1,3$ entry of the matrix $Q^4$.  That is, it is the $1,3$ entry of the matrix $Q^4$, where
$$
Q = \pmatrix{0.3& 0.7& 0\\
0.4 &0 &  0.6\\
0   & 0 & 0.5}.
$$
With a direct computation, [we see that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0.3%2C0.7%2C0%7D%2C%7B0.4%2C0%2C0.6%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%5E4) this probability is $0.7014$.  It follows that the desired probability is equal to $1 - 0.7014 = 0.2986$.